# Parallels between Hecate and the Devil?

Tags: greek, comparative, the-devil, witchcraft, crossroads

Hecate was [associated with crossroads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hecate#Goddess_of_the_crossroads), just as the devil was.

**Do the similarities end there? Could Hecate qualify as a devil figure?**

Comment: Can you expand further what you mean by "with crossroads?"

Comment: Delectable question!  Hecate is definitely a "dark" goddess, associated with witchcraft. Lot of material so it may take me some time to answer.

Comment: Crossroads are associated to the supernatural. It would not surprise me if this is an ancient idea (Hecate) that was later considered pagan and thus devil related.

Answer (score 0):

> Hecate was associated with crossroads,

That's why her Latin name is Trivia (tri = 3, via = road).

The association with the Christian devil is something that solidified during the re-appreciation of Hellenism and other civilizations in the 19th and 20th century.

The association of the devil with crossroads in itself is a result of Medieval tradition of burying criminals and suicides at the crossroads.

Comment: I think you're right, but adding some sources would make this a good answer. Also, a minor quibble, but from what I understand her Latin name is also Hecate, but she was often called Trivia. Looking at the Theoi page, it seems only Seneca calls her that in his *Medea*, but perhaps you know of other sources? Lewis and Short mention that Lucretius, Propertius, and Vergil write of a Trivia, but they seem to refer to Diana instead.

Answer (score -2):

Being that Hecate's symbol is a lit torch or "light" You may tie that back to the meaning of the name Lucifer.

And if you can wrap your head around the idea that before being cast out Lucifer being the left hand of yahweh or the maintenance team leader of his creation (like Hecate) stole a power from him hiding it (in an apple bearing tree). God since lost his power to communicate with humanity and change things whenever faith (being the source of his power) is waivered hence why he had to send his son to die for humanity instead of just changing his rules and snapping his finger to save caged children, raped babies, whatever displeases humans. (He just simply can't anymore) A theory stating that just like hecate, Lucifer has done the same.

Do some of your own searching with an open mind that humans have just messed up history.